# REST API with versioned data and differential endpoint : optimizing bandwidth and performance

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sails.js, database-versioning

My NodeJS project is based on SailsJS, itself using ExpressJS.

Its API will be used by mobile apps to fetch their data from it.

The tricky part is I don't want the client apps to fetch the whole data tree every time there is a change in the database.

The client only needs to download a differential between the data it's already got and the data on the server.

To achieve that I thought of using git on the server. That is create a repository and save all endpoints as a json file in the repo. Each save will trigger an automatic commit.

Then I could create a specific API endpoint that will accept a commit sha as a parameter and return a diff between that and git HEAD.

[This post](http://chapeau.freevariable.com/2011/06/restful-manipulation-of-versioned-data.html) by William Benton comforted me with this idea.

I'm now looking for any tips that could help me get this working based on the language and frameworks cited above :

- I'd like to see a proof of concept of this in action but couldn't find one
- I couldn't find an easy way to use git with NodeJS yet.
- I'm not sure how to parse the returned diff on client apps developed with the IONIC framework, so AngularJS.

Note : The api will only be readable. All DB movement will be triggered by a custom web back-end used by few users.

Answer (score 0):

I used the ideas in that post for an [experimental configuration-management service](https://github.com/willb/wallaroo/).  That code is in Erlang and I can't offer Node-specific suggestions, but I have some general advice.

Calling out to git itself wasn't a great option at the time from any of the languages I was interested in using.  Using git as a generic versioned-object store actually works surprisingly well, but using git plumbing commands is a pain (and slow, due to all of the forking) and there were (again, at the time) limitations to all of the available native git libraries.

I wound up implementing my own persistent trie data structure and put a git-like library interface atop it.  The nice thing about doing this is that your diffs can be sensitive to the data format you're storing; if you call out to git, you're stuck with finding a serialization format for your data that is amenable to standard diffs.  (Without a diffable format, though, you can still send back a sequence of operations to the client to replay on whatever stale objects they have.)